# MySQL: Use select in update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the query:

```sql
update movies
    SET name = 'example'
    where id = (select MAX(id) from movies);
```

and I need update last record.

Currently I get the error:

> .#1093 - You can't specify target table 'movies' for update in FROM clause

Comment: you should never run a query like this. it will break your data

Comment: *"you should never run a query like this. it will break your data"* @YourCommonSense i assume you are assuming here that the id column is a `PRIMARY KEY` ? If so you are most likely right as you shouldn't update your primary keys..

Comment: @RaymondNijland it doesn't matter. the data would become inconsistent in a concurrent environment such as a web-server. **There always should be certain id to update a record**

Comment: oh yes that is what you meant with your first comment @YourCommonSense now i understand what you meant after a coffee break.. You indeed risk on heavy concurrent environment that records can get updated with the same id or can simply fail when id column has a `PRIMARY KEY` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
update movies
    set name = 'example'
    order by id desc
    limit 1;
```

MySQL has a limitation on `update` and `delete` queries where it does not allow the table being referenced to be in a subquery in the `set` or `where` clauses.

You could also express this using `join`:

```
update movies m join
       (select max(m2.id) from movies m2) m2
       on m2.max_id = m.id
    set m.name = 'example';
```

But I find `order by` and `limit` to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the query:

```
select MAX(id) id from movies
```

inside another `select`:

```
update movies
SET name = 'example'
where id = (select t.id from (select MAX(id) id from movies) t);
```

Comment: topicstarter (@MiaadP) and future readers i would go with this one if you need database portability, as `LIMIT` is not a valid ANSI/ISO SQL (as the question is also tagged with `SQL`) and only runs in limitted database systems like MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL and SQLite

Comment: To be fair, if you're using SQL server, the original query posted in the question will work. And the question is about MySQL (which could've been made clear in the title)

Comment: *"To be fair, if you're using SQL server, the original query posted in the question will work."* @Qirel the `SQL` tag is not related to `SQL Server` on this website to be fair.. The `SQL` tag is about `ANSI/ISO SQL` standards.

Comment: True, but the question *is about MySQL*, so your comment is sort of irrelevant (its not a general SQL question, its a question about MySQL)